# React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by WithStyles

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am new to ReactJS. By creating one project, I come across one problem with 'withStyles'. I have one class component called 'Category' and in this component I call another class component called 'CreateCategory' which is about a form for creating new category. whenever i export CreateCategory using withStyles, I always get error 'React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by WithStyles(CreateCategory)'
could anyone help me ???
Thanks in advance
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post *actual* code instead of images of code. [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeStyles` returns a hook which you are passing to `withStyles`. This is what throws you that error. You should just pass on the styles to withStyles instead without the use of makeStyles

```
const styles = (theme) => createStyles({...});

...


export default withStyles(styles)(CreateCategory);
```

Comment: Actually, I don't really understand what hook is, but thanks so much. You saved me now :)

Comment: to understand react-hooks, please have a look at the documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html